# Why my edit page didn't work in Laravel? I used vue.js

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

Basically, I'm doing a dashboard to view the details. If the user want to edit the their details. They should click the edit button to edit it.If i click the edit button it's didn't response anything.  Now the edit didn't work. I couldn't find the problem. I attach my codes over here. [image]

index.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.main')

@section('content')
    <div class="justpaddingside" role="main" >
        <div class="row w-100 Bfont">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <div class="havence-content">
                    <div class="havence-content-body">
                        <div class="dashboardbg">
                            <div class="x_title" >
                                <img src="https://img.icons8.com/bubbles/50/000000/important-mail.png" class="rounded float-left" >  
                                <h2 class="p-3 font-weight-bold">Email Reminder Dashboard</h2> 
                                <h4 class="text-right">{{date('d-m-Y')}}</h4>
                                <h5 class="text-right">{{date('H:i:s')}}</h5>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-12 text-right"> 
                                <a href="mail" class="btn btn-danger badge-pill"  > Create New Template </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="contentbg p-5">
                            <div class="row w-100">
                                <div class="havence-content-datatable table-responsive">
                                <table class="table table-hover table-info"  cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                                    <thead class="">
                                        <tr>
                                            <th scope="col">ID</th>
                                            <th scope="col">Subject</th>
                                            <th scope="col">Message</th>
                                            <th scope="col">Condition</th>
                                            <th scope="col">Module Name</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        @foreach ($mailTemplates as $mailTemplate)
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>{{$mailTemplate->id}}</th>
                                            <th>{{$mailTemplate->subject}} </th>
                                            <th>{{$mailTemplate->message}} </th>
                                            <th>{{$mailTemplate->condition_id}} </th>
                                            <th>{{$mailTemplate->mod_name}}</th>

                                            <td class="text-right">
                                                <a href='edit/{id}' class="btn btn-danger badge-pill" style="width:80px" >EDIT </a>
                                                <form action="{{ route('havence.automail.delete', $mailTemplate) }}" method="POST">
                                                    @csrf
                                                    @method('DELETE')
                                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
                                                </form>
                                            </td>

                                        </tr>
                                        @endforeach
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    {!! Form::open(['method'=>'post', 'id'=> 'delete-frm']) !!}
    @method('DELETE')
    @csrf
    {!! Form::close() !!}


</div>


@endsection

@push('stylesheets')
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.16/datatables.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/css/select2.min.css">
@endpush

@push('scripts')
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.16/datatables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert2@7.19.3/dist/sweetalert2.all.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/js/select2.min.js"></script>
@endpush

@section('page-js')
    <script>


    </script>
@endsection
```

AutoMailController.php

```
 public function edit($id)
    {
        $mailTemplates=AutoEmailTemplate::find($id);
        return view('havence.automail.edit')->with('mailTemplates', $mailTemplates);
    }
```

web.php

```
Route::get('api/email/create', ['as' => 'email.create', 'uses' => 'Havence\AutoMailController@create']);
    Route::get('automail/mail', 'Havence\AutoMailController@mail');
    Route::get('automail/index',['as'=>'email.index','uses' => 'Havence\AutoMailController@index']);
    Route::get('automail/edit/{id}',['as'=>'email.edit','uses' => 'Havence\AutoMailController@edit']);
    Route::get('automail/delete',['as'=>'email.delete','uses' => 'Havence\AutoMailController@destroy']);
```

Comment: no error? is there any errors in the console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use :

```
<a href='{{ route("email.edit",["id"=>$mailTemplate->id]) }}' class="btn btn-danger badge-pill" style="width:80px" >EDIT </a>
```

Comment: its showing View [havence.automail.edit] not found. I think my route giving problem is it? @IIIya

Answer (score 0):

You're not passing the id from your href and user laravel string interpolation '{{ $variable }}'.

```
<a href='edit/{{$mailTemplate->id}}' class="btn btn-danger badge-pill" style="width:80px" >EDIT </a>
```

also if you want to open the route in another tab add target="_blank" in your 'a' tag.

```
<a href='edit/{{$mailTemplate->id}}' target='_blank' class="btn btn-danger badge-pill" style="width:80px" >EDIT </a>
```

Comment: its showing View [havence.automail.edit] not found.

Comment: Is it there is any problem in my route?

Comment: @NavanithaMoorthy check if the blade file exist.

Comment: my blade is exist

Comment: but idk how to connection @Poldo

Answer (score 0):

what about replacing :

```
<a href='edit/{id}' class="btn btn-danger badge-pill" style="width:80px" >EDIT </a>
```

with:

```
<a href={{'edit/'.$mailTemplate->id}} class="btn btn-danger badge-pill" style="width:80px" >EDIT </a>
```

Comment: i try used the method. It's showing 
InvalidArgumentException thrown with message "View [havence.automail.edit] not found." @Jmielh

Comment: Is it there is any problem in my route? @Jmielh

Comment: you have a problem with the VIEW file, not the route. Create the view as it is asking for  or move the view to the correct folder if you already have created it.

Comment: so, now i need to create a View file is it?

Comment: Yes, you need to create a View file to show the edit options in a form and then create a function in the controller to update the info. I don't know what you are editing or what fields can be edited, but for sure you will need to update the data in the DB.